# EspoCRM: Send custom email when a comment is written in the Stream of a custom entity

Tags: espocrm

I created a custom entity named "Project". Each time a comment is written in the Stream section of a project, I need to send the comment via email to the comment author AND to the target account of the project.

The email subject must be structured as follows: "[<Project_ID>] New comment on <Project_Name>". Ex: *[123] New comment on Sample Project.*

Does EspoCRM allow to solve a problem like this? If true, please provide guidance, useful docs, etc. I have explored the docs but no success to solve this specific problem.

Comment: there are many ways to achive this.. you can override controller, afterCreate hook in repositery, or even can define a custom hook for that, or a workflow (if you have advanced pack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some good information:

- The entity name is `Note`, so every record on stream panel is a Note entity.
- `Note` entity is not customizable by design, because it is core entity.
- A way to send emails conditionally in Espocrm is [Formula](https://docs.espocrm.com/administration/formula/#extemailsend).
- `Note` is not customizable, so cannot write formula for it.
- To make it customizable, create this file:
- Path: `custom/Espo/Custom/Resources/metadata/scopes/Note.json`
- Contect: `{"customizable":true}`